# How can i convert the data from Firestore into dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I can access their location from Firestore. What I need is to be able to convert the data from Firestore into dart language. Then I have to do the listing Firestore locations from closest to farthest.
**This is my Firestore:** [image]

**This is my code:**

```
import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class FavoriteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FavoriteScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _FavoriteScreen createState() => _FavoriteScreen();
}

class _FavoriteScreen extends State<FavoriteScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  double calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 -
        c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }

  Future<Position> getLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    return position;
  }

  Future<double> tryLocation(GeoPoint geoPointLocation) async {
    var location = await getLocation();
    var findAway = calculateDistance(location.latitude, location.longitude,
        geoPointLocation.latitude, geoPointLocation.longitude);

    print(findAway);

    return Future.value(findAway);
  }

  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> chnageList(
      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.docs.length; i++) {
      GeoPoint location = snapshot.docs[i].data()["location"];
      double getDistance = 0;
      var aaa = tryLocation(location)
          .then((value) => {getDistance = value, print(getDistance)});

      //item.distance = getDdistance;


      print(getDistance);
    }
    //orderby
    return snapshot;
  }

  final Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("1favori");
```

**more:**

```
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot =
                snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>;

            querySnapshot = chnageList(querySnapshot);

            return ListView(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 16.8),
                  height: 724.8,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: querySnapshot.size,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.8, right: 12),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 214.8,
                        width: 188.4,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.8, bottom: 50),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.6),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                querySnapshot.docs[index].data()['image'],
                                maxHeight: 200,
                                maxWidth: 200),
                          ),
                        ),
```

How can i list Firestore locations from closest to farthest?
[image]

Comment: The documentation says : "limit() and orderBy() are not supported at the moment. limit() could be used to limit docs inside each hash individually which would result in running limit on all 9 hashes inside the specified radius. orderBy() is first run on geohashes in the library, hence appending orderBy() with another feild wouldn't produce expected results. Alternatively documents can be sorted on client side."

Comment: So I can't sort by the locations I got from Firestore, right?

Comment: At the bottom: https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire2.

Comment: I get it, thanks

Comment: @mariofrancois Could you please post an answer with your findings? That way the information is more likely to be found by other people who might have this issue in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help the other: The documentation says : "limit() and orderBy() are not supported at the moment. limit() could be used to limit docs inside each hash individually which would result in running limit on all 9 hashes inside the specified radius. orderBy() is first run on geohashes in the library, hence appending orderBy() with another feild wouldn't produce expected results. Alternatively documents can be sorted on client side."
At the bottom: [here](http://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire2)